# Como poner un event listener a un div en typescript

Tags: html, typescript, eventos

estoy intentando hacer un div que oiga cuando pressione (o suelte, da igual) la tecla esc, cuando tenga el mouse encima del div. Por una razón que no entiendo si en el siguiente código pongo simplemente keypress y presiono una tecla si que lo recibe, en cambio si uso keypress.esc o pressiono la tecla esc no escucha nada.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const element = document.getElementById("a");
  element?.addEventListener('keypress.esc', this.funcion, false);
}
```

```html
<div id="a" height="200px" width="200px"></div>
```

Curiosamente si en vez de ponerselo al div lo pongo en la pagina con un addGlobalEventListener, entonces si que lo esucha.
Muchas gracias

Comment: prueba con `keypress.escape`

Comment: @Cris223511.dev el [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event) esta desaconsejado (obsoleto), lo siento, no creo que sea una buena opción.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr esto utilizo 3 eventListeners para saber cuando está sobre el elemento y cuando sale de el y el keydown para detectar el Escape:

```js
const el = document.getElementById("a");
let isOver = false;


el.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
  isOver = true;
});

el.addEventListener('mouseleave', event => {
  isOver = false;
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if (event.code === "Escape" && isOver) {
    el.innerText = "Texto despues de ESC";
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="a" height="200px" width="200px">texto antes de ESC</div>
```